# Converting SQLite to PDF

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am developing an Android application and got a SQLite database in it, which has quite a lot of rows and columns. Showing those inside the application is no problem, but I want to export the information of the database as a PDF file to upload it to Dropbox or the SD card.

I found a way to create a PDF file within the application from a bitmap file, but that doesn't help me much. The information of the database can only be seen in the application by scrolling around, as it is to big for the screen. Is there a solution for this problem?

Exporting a screenshot as PDF won't help me much as not the whole database can be seen within one screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look for some reporting solution for example http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports possibly on the server side.

You can also try iText which is very low level.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the bitmap in your software from or in parallel with the generation of what the users sees, write it out as a file, and give it to the pdf generator.

Comment: But what the user sees is not the total database

Comment: You seemed to say they can see the whole thing by scrolling around, so write out the entirety of what they scroll around in, not the part that's on the screen at any given instant.  Though if that's huge, it may be better to present it to the pdf converter already as a series of pages.  Another option you could look at would be formatting your code using some kind of markup language (postcript, LaTeX, RTF, maybe even HTML) and feeing that to a PDF converter which supports it.  For textual information that should be a lot more efficient.

Comment: Thanks alot! You gave me THE hint , i will format to with an markup language and convert it directly. thanks alot!